# Read each line in text file and save it in a variable dynamically

Tags: python

The script runs but only the last items in the text files are being outputted. I'd like to start from the first item. The variables are `timestamp` and `val`. Their values change after every read in the file.

I have this so far:

```
while True:
    with open ("time.txt",'r') as FF:
        for line in FF:
            lines.append(line)
            timestamp = line

    with open ("val.txt",'r') as PP:
        for line in PP:
            lines.append(line)
            val = line

    data= '{ "timestamp": "' + timestamp + '","temp": ' + str(val) + '}'

    print(data) #print payload for reference
```

I think I'm missing something like incrementing after every loop... but I don't know how to implement it here.

What's expected:

1. read line
2. save to variable
3. repeat and replace current variable value with new value

- timestamps sample: `2020-02-22T23:50:00Z`
- val sample: `24`

thanks for your time!

Comment: So, do you want to save all lines in these variables? Isn't the `lines` list there for this reason?

Comment: You should replace `lines` with 2 lists `timestamps` and `vals` and then do `vals.append(line)`. You can also shorten this to `vals = PP.readlines()` instead of the loop

Comment: You've described what the code is currently doing but I think you need to include more details about what exactly you _want_ it to be doing, especially with the `timestamp` and `val`.  What's the overall goal you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: "only the last items in the text files are being outputted" - actually, nothing is outputtted, IMHO, because there's no print() statement

Comment: @ThomasWeller there is. I didn't include it here sir. Variables are printed at the end.

Comment: Something doesn't add up. Your code matches exactly to your expectations: It reads a line, saves the value to a variable, then moves on and replaces the value. You have to be more clear on what is exactly the problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo yes sir it reads but only the last items. It doesn't move to the next line, or even start at the first line.

Comment: You are wrong. You are confused between the output you see and what actually happens inside the code

Comment: It starts in the first line and reads **all** lines. You're just not doing anything with it. Add a `print` statement inside the loops and see the difference

Comment: According to your comments, this is obviously not your full code. It will be helpful to see how you actually use those variables to better understand your problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo I've updated the code sir. I hope it clears it

Comment: Do you expect to print this `data` variable for each line? Because right now you just use the last values, which is the behavior you observed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to print matching pairs of `timestamp` and `val` from both files, you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate both files at the same time:

```py
with open ("time.txt",'r') as FF, open ("val.txt",'r') as PP:
    for timestamp, val in zip(FF, PP):
        data= '{ "timestamp": "' + timestamp + '","temp": ' + val + '}'
        print(data) #print payload for reference
```